# Current tableView cell index when scrolling tablecells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have a tableView with some table cells in it

I have some logic to implement in one cell (Eg: cell at row 7) depending on cell at row 6. This works fine when tableView first loaded. But when the tablecell is scrolled, I get error index out of bounds so I used below code to get current cell index path but this crashes my app

```
let currentCellRow = tableView.indexPath(for: tableCell)!.row  //For cell 7
 //Get cell 6
 if let previousCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: (currentCellRow - 1), section: 0))  { }
```

Pls advice how to proceed i.e., how to get the index of the previous cell as well as the current cell when the table view is scrolled

Comment: You better implement the logic in your model, e.g. do not rely on retrieving cells from the table view, in order to modify other cells. You should set up cell at row `7` depending on the *data model* of row `6`, not on the *cell* at row `6`

Comment: In addition to the above comment, in viewcontroller you might also want to check if the array `indexPathsForVisibleRows` contains index path of the previous row.